# Spring Property From Command Line

Tags: java, spring, command-line, properties

I've a Spring Profile enabled app with two profiles [cat|dog] and running with desired profile is fine in Idea using Maven:

clean compile package exec:java -Dspring.profiles.active=dog

I wish to run the packaged jar from command line but can't seem to find the right syntax to set the profile.  I've tried the follwing but none are correct:

```
java -cp myShadedJar-1.0-SO-static.jar org.my.package.Main --spring.profiles.active=dog

java -cp myShadedJar-1.0-SO-static.jar org.my.package.Main -Drun.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=dog"

java -cp myShadedJar-1.0-SO-static.jar org.my.package.Main -Drun.arguments="spring.profiles.active=dog"

java -cp myShadedJar-1.0-SO-static.jar org.my.package.Main -Dspring.profiles.active=dog
```

What's the correct way to pass a Spring property when running from CLI?

Thanks in advance,
KA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles) you can set a JVM Property or an Env Var.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dog myShadedJar-1.0-SO-static.jar
```

or ( *NIX Systems)

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dog java -jar myShadedJar-1.0-SO-static.jar
```

Comment: What I was doing wrong was adding the -Dparameter after the .jar